# Unable to do a word count of a file through ssh in unix shell scripting

Tags: if-statement, ssh, word-count, wc

I need to go another server and perform a word count. Based on the count variable I will perform a if else logic.
However i am unable to do a word count and further unable to compare the variable value in if condition.

Error:

> wc: cannot open the file v.txt

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh u1@s1 "cd ~/path1/ | fgrep-f abc.csv xyz.csv > par.csv | a=$(wc -l par.csv)| if ["$a" == "0"];
then echo "success"
fi"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, although the `wc` program is named for 'word count', `wc -l` actually counts *lines* not words. I assume that is what you want even though it isn't what you said.

A shell pipline `one | two | three` runs things in *parallel* with (only) their stdout and stdin connected; thus your command runs one subshell that changes directory to `~/path1` and immediately exits with no effect on anything else, and at the same time tries to run `fgrep-f` (see below) in a different subshell which has not changed the directory and thus probably can't find any file, and in a third subshell does the assignment a= (see below) which also immediately exits so it cannot be used for anything.

You want to do things *sequentially*:

```
ssh u@h 'cd path1; fgrep -f abc.csv xyz.csv >par.csv; a=$(wc -l par.csv); if [ "$a" == "0" ] ...'
# you _might_ want to use && instead of ; so that if one command fails
# the subsequent ones aren't attempted (and possibly go further wrong)
```

Note several other important changes I made:

- the command you give `ssh` to send the remote must be in singlequotes `'` not doublequotes `"` if it contains any dollar as yours does (or backtick); with `"` the `$(wc ...)` is done in the *local* shell *before* sending the command to the remote
- you don't need `~/` in `~/path1` because `ssh` (or really `sshd`) always starts in your home directory
- there is no common command or program `fgrep-f`; I assume you meant the program `fgrep` with the flag `-f`, which must be separated by a space. Also `fgrep` although traditional is not standard (POSIX); `grep -F` is preferred
- you must have a space after `[` and before `]`

However, this won't do what you probably want. The value of `$a` will be something like `0 par.csv` or `1 par.csv` or `999 par.csv`; it will *never* equal `0` so your "success" branch will never happen. In addition there's no need to do these in separate commands: if your actual goal is to check that there are no occurrences in xyz.csv of the (exact/non-regexp) strings in abc.csv both in path1, you can just do

```
ssh u@h 'if ! grep -qFf path1/abc.csv path1/xyz.csv; then echo success; fi'
# _this_ case would work with " instead of ' but easier to be consistent
```

`grep` (always) sets its exit status to indicate whether it found anything or not; flag `-q` tells it *not* to output any matches. So `grep -q ...` just sets the status to true if it matched and false otherwise; using `!` inverts this so that if `grep` does not match anything, the `then` clause is executed.

If you want the line count for something else as well, you can do it with a pipe

```
'a=$( fgrep -Ff path1/abc.csv path1/xyz.csv | wc -l ); if [ $a == 0 ] ...'
```

Not only does this avoid the temp file, when the input to `wc` is stdin (here the pipe) and not a named file, it outputs only the number and no filename -- `999` rather than `999 par.csv` -- thus making the comparison work right.